# .htaccess File isn´t working.

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2, password-protection

I want to protect the complete /var/www/html/* area with a Password, but exclude one File.
I tried this Code:

```
<Files *.*>
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Service-Login"
AuthUserFile /path/tomypasswdfile/...
Require valid-user
</Files>

<Files /index.alternetive.php>
#Order allow,deny
Require all granted
#Allow from All
#Allow from env=allow
#Satisfy any

</Files>
```

The Login is functioning, but for ALL files including the "index.alternetive.php"-File.

My apache2 is running on Ubuntu-Xenial.

Thanks Alot

Answer (score 1):

[`Files`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#files) doesn't work on path names, but only on file names. If you want a specific path, you must enclose it in a `Directory` directive or put it in a .htaccess where it belongs. In your case this seems to be the root directory

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Service-Login"
AuthUserFile /path/tomypasswdfile/...
Require valid-user

<Files index.alternetive.php>
Require all granted
</Files>
```

Also look at the spelling, e.g. `alternetive` vs `alternative`.

Answer (score 0):

The file name is your problem.  Change it to something like index_alternetive.php and that should work for you.